# Prove a function is constant under certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth and such that for every $x$ 
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^2}dy < \infty$$
>   Prove that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Two observations, not sure if useful: the integrand is even, so this is equivalent to saying $$\int_x^\infty \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{(x-y)^2} dy < \infty.$$ That $f$ is constant forces the integral on the LHS to be always $0$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $f$ is not constant, then $f'(a)\ne 0$ for some $a.$ Thus for some $\delta >0,$ $|f(y)-f(a)|/|y-a|>|f'(a)|/2$ for $a<y<a+\delta.$ Taking $x=a,$ the integral of interest is at least

$$\int_{a}^{a+\delta}\frac{|f(a)-f(y)|}{|a-y|^2}dy \ge \frac{|f'(a)|}{2}\int_{a}^{a+\delta}\frac{1}{y-a}dy =\infty,$$

contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch for a proof:** from the Taylor's theorem we have that
$$
f(x)=f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)+O(|x-y|^2),\quad  \text{ when }|x-y|\to 0
$$
And because the integral converges then for any chosen $\epsilon >0$ there is some $\delta >0$ such that
$$
\int_{x-\delta }^{x+\delta }\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{(x-y)^2}\,\mathrm d y=\int_{x-\delta }^{x+\delta }\left|\frac{f'(y)}{x-y}+ \frac{O(|x-y|^2)}{(x-y)^2} \right|\,\mathrm d y<\epsilon 
$$
Because $f$ is smooth then $f'$ is continuous in $[x-\delta ,x+\delta ]$ so $f'$ is bounded here, and also its bounded the term $O(|x-y|^2)/(x-y)^2$ (check the definition of big Oh, or instead of big Oh notation use the Taylor's remainder).

If you show that $f'(x)=0$ we are done. Can you continue from here?

> What happen if $f'(x)\neq 0$?

Comment: Wow, how do you make the spoiler thingy?

Comment: @Vincent: just click the edit button, you'll see the raw markdown (`>!` in this case)